About the limit of the integration of a continuous function on a unit hyper cube
Problem description:
The task is to compute the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0, 1]^n} f(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n) \, dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n,
$$
where $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a given continuous function.
I have solved this problem by the Weierstrass approximation theorem, but my instructor pointed out that there exists a more straightforward method from definitions. So I tried to think about this problem intuitively, and found that as long as each $x_i$ has some distances with 1, their product could be very small. So initially I try to divide the hyper n cube into two part: One is $[0, \delta]^n$ for some $\delta\in(0, 1)$ , the other is its complement. For any fixed delta, when $n$ goes to infinity, $f(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n)$ goes to $f(0)$ when we consider the case in the first part. Okay now could we approximate $$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0, 1]^n} f(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n) \, dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n,
$$ by $$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0, \delta]^n} f(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n) \, dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n=f(0),
$$ and let $\delta\to 1$ ?
I suddenly comes up to this argument when I writing this post, originally I'm just worried about the volume of the remaining part does not vanishes when $n\to\infty$. But now I think since I can prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0, \delta]^n} f(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n) \, dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n=f(0),$ for any $\delta\in(0, 1)$, taking the limit about $\delta $ for the constant function f(0) also makes sense. Could any one help me verify this argument?
Update: When I review my proof for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0, \delta]^n} f(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n) \, dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n=f(0)$, I found something quite strange: No matter what the $\delta$ is,  $vol([0, \delta]^n)\to 0$ as  $n\to \infty$. But then we have $\int_{[0, \delta]^n} f(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n) \, dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n\leq (sup_{x\in [0,1]}f(x))\times (vol([0, \delta]^n))\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$. What's going wrong with this argument? Maybe in this case I can't switch the order of taking the limit.

I think you have the right idea but the wrong set. Consider the hypercube centered at $0$ with side $1 - \delta$. What is the volume of that? What does that tell you?

The volume is $(1-\delta)^n$, which tends to zero when n tends to infinity.

Can you now combine this observation with your original attempt?

Sorry I can't since I have found my attempt is not correct, the order of taking limit can't be switched in this case.
